# "authorization required" and @OnlyCurrentDoc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can you avoid the "authorization required" on a Google Sheet if the function being called is on its own built-in apps script file, using the @OnlyCurrentDoc scope, and the methods used act entirely locally to the active sheet?

Here's the gist: I want to call a function from a custom menu on a Google Sheet.  The function gets the active sheet and inserts a new row at the top, with some pre-populated values (relative to the sheet) :

```
function addNewPO() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var data = sheet.getRange('PO Numbers!A3').getValue();
  var nextPONum = data+1;

  sheet.insertRowsBefore(3,1);  // This inserts a row after the first row  
  sheet.getRange('PO Numbers!A3').setValue(nextPONum);     // set next PO number
  sheet.getRange('PO Numbers!C3').setValue(new Date());    // set current date
  sheet.getRange('PO Numbers!B3').activate();              // set final focus
}
```

Also, I put the @OnlyCurrentDoc lines at the top of the script to narrow the scope:

```
 /**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
```

I want to call this from a custom menu:

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'add new PO...', functionName: 'addNewPO'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Purchase Orders', menuItems);
}
```

but as you might suspect, it prompts "Authorization Required"

I wasn't sure if the "Authorization Required" is a pre-flight requirement of running *any* scripts whatsoever, or if with a few more lines of restrictive logic it would be considered sand-boxed enough to avoid explicitly authorizing its highly localized behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: Using the `@OnlyCurrentDoc` decoration prevents the displayed OAuth from being deemed "unsafe by default" but cannot ever replace user authorization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script requires authorization to access the active spreadsheet. The only way to do stuff in  the current file without any authorization is through [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions): onOpen or onEdit or custom functions. Any direct call to script functions through menu or otherwise will  need authorization and trigger auth flow. You may be able to leverage onEdit with a checkbox to trigger a script.

Comment: Thanks - that was my confusion: Based on real-world workflow I'd already wrapped that function into an onEdit and there has never been an authorization need.  It's only when it's called from the menu, which really had me scratching my head. :D